# Change the show and hide position of elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a couple of buttons. When clicked, they're supposed to hide and show an HTML element. They work fine but when I click them the HTML element's hide and show position is top left. I want it to show and hide from center instead of top left.

Here's the code.

HTML:

```
<div class="section">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
</div>
<button class="button1">Click to hide the section!</button>
<button class="button2">Click to show the section!</button>
```

jQuery:

```
$(".button1").click(function(){
  $(".section").hide("200");
});

$("button2").click(function(){
  $(".section").show("200");
});
```

Comment: You can use jQuery UI for the slide effect.

Comment: You can also use slideDown/slideUp on jQuery API
http://api.jquery.com/slidedown/

Comment: This has nothing to do with jQuery, because there is nothing wrong with the jQuery code you provided. If you first run the page without clicking any buttons does this section align in the center of the page?

Comment: @MugiwaraUK thanks very much. It worked!